# What is the best way to implement a button displayed and hidden in real-time in a specific time?

Tags: android

I have a button that allows the user to join a scheduled meeting in a specific timing (i.e 12:00 PM) and is hidden by default. When the screen having this button is entered, i call a service that returns that timing. 
The button is supposed to be displayed starting from the timing and for 15 mins. So if the user is viewing the screen and the button is hidden and the timing is reached the button should appear then after 15 min it disappears.
The returned timing may be a day before!!
How can i implement this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scedule](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html) and LiveData for this.

```
Timer().schedule(5000) {
    TODO("Do smth")
}
```

In your case, when service is called and passed via broadcast receiver to MainActivity, you could schedule 2 times and update view.

```
// schedule button visibility
Timer().schedule(scheduledTimeInMillisec - currentMillisec){
     livedata.value = true     
} 

// schedule hiding button
Timer().schedule(scheduledTimeInMillisec - currentMillisec + 1000*60*15){
     livedata.value = false
}
```